# Microsoft RDP Client Control not loading outside of compatibility mode in IE10

Tags: html, vbscript, activex

I have a site that implements the above ActiveX control on a webpage, however it doesn't work in IE 10 I have to run the site in compatibility mode and add the site to the trusted sites.

ActiveX control code below...

```
<object language="vbscript" 
        ID="MsRdpClient" 
        CLASSID="CLSID:4eb89ff4-7f78-4a0f-8b8d-2bf02e94e4b2"  
        onreadystatechange="OnControlLoad" 
        onerror="OnControlError" 
        height="0" 
        width="0">
</object>
```

Any idea on how I can support IE 10 without forcing users to use compatibility mode?

i am looking to migrate this to a HTML5 version so am looking for a short term fix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else stumbles upon this - there was no way (that I could find) to do the above and I implemented a HTML5 version, using a product called AccessNow by Ericom.